# How to assign datetime type to multiple columns in data frame and keep time UTC offset information?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timezone

The following assignment of `dtypes`

```
data = {"Naive": ["2020-11-27 09:00:00", "2020-11-27 10:20:00"],
        "UTC+1": ["2020-11-27T09:26:24+01:00", "2020-11-27T10:20:03+01:00"], 
        "UTC+2": ["2020-11-27T09:26:24+02:00", "2020-11-27T11:44:55+02:00"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df.astype({"Naive":"datetime64[ns, Europe/Moscow]",
           "UTC+1":"datetime64[ns, Europe/London]", 
           "UTC+2":"datetime64[ns], Europe/Warsaw"
```

yields the error

```
TypeError: data is already tz-aware pytz.FixedOffset(60), unable to set specified tz: Europe/London
```

which makes some sense, since indeed the strings in `UTC+1` and `UTC+2` indicate the UTC offsets, however this works:

```
pd.DataFrame(data["UTC+1"], dtype="datetime64[ns, Europe/London]")
```

How to assign the `dtypes` to multiple columns as done with `astype()` to yield:

```
                      Naive                      UTC+1                      UTC+2
0 2020-11-27 09:00:00+03:00  2020-11-27 09:26:24+01:00  2020-11-27 09:26:24+02:00
1 2020-11-27 10:20:00+03:00  2020-11-27 10:20:03+01:00  2020-11-27 11:44:55+02:00
```

? why is the behaviour of setting the type when creating the data frame versus via `astype()` different? one casting to UTC and the other keeping the UTC offset/time zone?

Comment: note that your code snipped `pd.DataFrame(data["UTC+1"], dtype="datetime64[ns, Europe/London]")` doesn't actually parse the time zone you supply; it leaves you with a fixed offset: `dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]`

Comment: @MrFuppes thanks a lot for making the distinction between time zone and UTC offset, since I was using the concepts loosely, for now I only care about UTC offsets - I think I will adjust the title of the question

Comment: ok if you just care about the offset, you can just parse with `pd.to_datetime`, that will automatically set the fixed offset. if you have naive datetime without offset specified but you know it's UTC, just set `utc=True`.